# ColdFusion/OAuth/Twitter API

Tags: coldfusion, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to integrate with Twitter using their OAuth API. I have downloaded and tried the CF implementation here: http://oauth.riaforge.org/ with no success. Anyone have a simple CF to Twitter OAuth example for authorizing a user, getting a token, and using it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ColdFusion plays really nice with java.  What I did is simply use the twitter4j lib (http://yusuke.homeip.net/twitter4j/en/index.html#introduction) to handle everything.  Works like a charm, and is far more comprehensive that you'd ever dream of writing yourself.  Plus, it's free.

I'd try that before I went banging my head against the wall trying to deal with signing oauth requests and reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

checkout this post my colleague wrote - the twitter 4j library recently change in the 2.2 update and the class is now an interface, so you have to modify the code a bit...

http://techblog.troywebconsulting.com/2011/09/authenticating-to-twitter-using-oauth-and-twitter4j-2-2x-api-with-coldfusion/

Answer (score 0):

Could try this one, but I didn't try it myself yet to know if it works any better than the one on RIA Forge.  I just found it while digging around.

http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/coldfusion/

It looks like RPX also supports OAuth, but again, I haven't tried it personally.  I am using them for an OpenID implementation, and they work great.

https://rpxnow.com/docs

Comment: Thanks, but the the google code link is the same as the one on RIAForge.

Comment: According to the official OAuth site, the two projects are the same, simply multiply hosted.