# How to Follow Twitter Users by API in Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, twitter, twitter-oauth, coldfusion-9

Oauth is pretty complicated but I think I got the authentication working. I got up to the point where I get the user to authorize on Twitter and I have the access token and access token secret. From here, I'm not sure how I use it to generate a request to follow a user.
I know that the url is: http://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/create.xml and that you can either pass in a user_id or screen_name
but does anyone have any example code in Coldfusion that I can see as to how the cfhttp call looks like with all the parameters?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coldfusion/OAuth/Twitter API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997708/coldfusion-oauth-twitter-api)

Answer (score 2):

Try  [(monkeh)Tweet Twitter API](http://monkehtweet.riaforge.org/). It supports most of the twitter API methods including follow a user. Easy & freaking cool CF open source by [Matt Gifford](http://www.mattgifford.co.uk/)